# Android - Webview with dark theme - Customize dark color background

Tags: android, webview, colors, themes, darkmode

In my app I have a webview that show some content.
I'm developing dark theme for my app.

I forced the dark theme of the webview with

```
if(WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
   WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(binding.messageContentLayout.webview.settings, WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON)
}
```

The webview have a black background, but the dark background of the app is #262626, how can I change the dark theme of the webview?

The webview show the body of an email, so I can't apply a css to change the colors.

[image: The webview black inside a gray background]

Comment: Do you have control over content of web view ? This looks like the content in web view is setting some color which does not match color of your application.

Comment: I don't have control over content of webview. 
In the content showed above there isn't any css or color. If I set the webview in dark mode the background is black, but I want to set the background to #262626.
The following is the HTML that show the example above.
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: medium;" xam-editor-container="true">AAAAA
   <div>
    ssss
   </div>
   <div>
    <br>
   </div></span>
 </body>
</html>